# Bootstrap in Dagre D3 is not correctly rendering

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dagre-d3, dagre

Hello i have a problem with rendering Bootstrap with
[Dagre D3](https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre-d3) in JavaScript. Dagre D3 is a Libary based on D3.
First Problem is that the star-glyphicon is only in the first node, but not in the second node. Why?
Second Problem is that the Dropdown Menu is not correctly rendering. It is only in the first node ( not in the second). when i click on the Dropdown Menu there does not Pop Up a menu. Does somebody have solution?

```html
<!doctype html>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bootstrap Nodes</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://cpettitt.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/dagre-d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id='panel' class='panel panel-primary'>
  <div class='panel-heading fixed-panel-head'>
    <h3 class='panel-title'>
      <h3 class='panel-title'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span> Sample</h3>
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class='panel-body fixed-panel-foot'>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style id="css">

  .fixed-panel-head {
    min-height: 40px;
    max-height: 40px;
  }

  .fixed-panel-foot {
    min-height: 60px;
    max-height: 60px;
  }

  .node g div {
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    color: #000;
  }

  .edgePath path {
    stroke: #333;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }

</style>

<svg id="svg-canvas" width=100% height=600></svg>

<script id="js">
  // Create the input graph
  var g = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph()
    .setGraph({})
    .setDefaultEdgeLabel(function() {
      return {};
    });

  var element = document.getElementById("panel");
  var elementHtml = element.outerHTML;

  g.setNode((1), {
    labelType: "html",
    label: elementHtml,
    rx: 5,
    ry: 5,
    padding: 0
  });

  g.setNode((2), {
    labelType: "html",
    label: elementHtml,
    rx: 5,
    ry: 5,
    padding: 0
  });
  g.setEdge(1, 2);


  var render = new dagreD3.render();

  // Set up an SVG group so that we can translate the final graph.
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    svgGroup = svg.append("g");

  // Run the renderer. This is what draws the final graph.
  render(d3.select("svg g"), g);

  // Center the graph
  var xCenterOffset = (svg.attr("width") - g.graph().width) / 2;
  svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + xCenterOffset + ", 20)");
  svg.attr("height", g.graph().height + 40);
</script>
```

Comment: ad 1. what browser do you use? on FF 51.0.1 and Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0 I see star glyphs on all nodes and Chrome 56.0.2924.87 and canary has glyph and dropdown missing on 2nd node... Boostrap dropdown doesn't work (on all browsers) cause it is JS component (sth like `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()` is required, more [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns))... I was not able to force dropdown to work within SVG tag but I gave it less than 5min of attention (maybe you will find someone else a bit wiser).

Comment: oh and here: `var xCenterOffset = (svg.attr("width") - g.graph().width) / 2;` you end up with NaN and end up with fail here `svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + xCenterOffset + ", 20)");` resulting in `translate(NaN, 20)`. This is due to the fact that you try to substract number from the string to be precise pixels from percentage and even more precise `'100%' - 135` in my browser

Comment: i use  google chrome version: 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Try with different id for each node each control. There will be mltiple field with id dropdownmenu1, out of which only one will work. Try to concacat with node id.